# MVC 5 - NonFactors Grid Entity Framework - server side filter

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5, grid, nonfactors-mvc-grid

Is it possible to process the filters from server side?
This happens because I work EntityFramework and with thousands of records.

I clarify that I am working with MVC 5

Answer (score 1):

`NonFactors` grid has already done that on the server side if you pass a proper `IQueryable` or `DbSet` as source.